# How to declare a DependencyProperty that could also be set without binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I know that I can declare a new DependencyProperty as such:

```
public String PropertyPath
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(PropertyPathProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PropertyPathProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyPathProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(PropertyPath), typeof(String),
        typeof(NotEmptyStringTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PropertyPath_PropertyChanged));

protected static void PropertyPath_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctl = d as NotEmptyStringTextBox;

    var binding = new Binding(ctl.PropertyPath)
    {
        ValidationRules = { new NotEmptyStringRule() },

        //  Optional. With this, the bound property will be updated and validation 
        //  will be applied on every keystroke. 
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    };

    ctl.StringBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

}
```

But then the UserControl can only recieve a string with the name of the property to bind, and bind to it.

What I would like is to be able to have the same kind of comportment as "classical" properties, which you can either bind to, or give a static value.
My usage would be a boolean that modifies the display state of a UserControl, either statically with a fixed value or dynamically with a binding, all depending on the use case.

Maybe the way I made my dependency Property in the first place is incorrect, but here is how I can use it:

```
<inputboxes:NotEmptyStringTextBox 
                Grid.Column="1"
                PropertyPath="Name"/>
```

This will bind the "Name" property from the DataContext, but I can't use it with a raw string, as it will make a BindingExpression error: "property not found"

EDIT:
I now have tried the following:

```
public bool Test
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(TestProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Test), typeof(bool),
        typeof(DamageTemplateListEditableUserControl));
```

I declared this new property, but I still cannot bind anything to it, only raw values are accepted

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. All dependency properties can be used like normal properties. In addition, they can be bound or have their values assigned by Style Setters, animations, etc.

Comment: When you declare a boolean dependency property in your control class, you can either write `<local:MyControl MyBool="True"/>` or `<local:MyControl MyBool="{Binding SomeBooleanSourceProperty}"/>`.

Comment: I updated my post to explain a bit more @Clemens

Comment: Instead of `PropertyPath="Name"` you would simply have `Property="{Binding Name}"` or `Property="Whatever"`. A "property path" would quite obviously only make sense for a Binding.

Comment: Do you mean I can *declare* a DependencyProperty directly inside the .xaml instead of the .cs file ?

Comment: No, you declare the dependency property as in your question, with `bool` as its type.

Comment: I kinda see what you mean, but I guess I still miss a little thing, in your reply, `Property` would not correspond to anything. So If I don't have to change anything in my declaration, I don't get how to make this work

Comment: `Property` would be a dependency property just like your `PropertyPath`. You may name it as you like (see `MyBool` above). Besides that, you already set your PropertyPath property without a Binding.

Comment: I am sorry I don't get it :( I don't see how it would work differently if I don't do any change but the name

Comment: You should understand that what you are doing with your PropertyPath property is a very special case. Creating a Binding that takes its Path from the value of a string dependency property is obviously not what you typically do with dependency properties. Probably read over this again: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Ok, this + the reply from @mm8 finally made me get it (I think) I'll try this without the callBack

Comment: Without the RelativeSource Binding in XAML, you would just have `ctl.StringBox.Text = (string)e.NewValue;` in the PropertyChangedCallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new binding in the callback. In fact, you don't need any callback at all.

Rename the dependency property to something better like "Text" and just bind the `Text` property of `StringBox` to the current value of your dependency property like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="StringBox"
    Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:NotEmptyStringTextBox},
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

You can then set or bind the dependency property as usual.

If you really want a "PropertyPath" property, it shouldn't be a dependency property that you can bind something to but rather a simple CLR property that you can set to a `string` that represents a *name* of a property to bind to.

This is for example how the `DisplayMemberPath` property of an `ItemsControl` is implemented.

Comment: If you don't mind to have a look at my edit, I thought I did what you meant, but I still can't bind anything to it

Comment: So you have defined a `bool` dependency property. What are you trying to do with it that doesn't work?

Comment: I can succesfully use it inside my UserControl (i bind it to Visibility with a converter) but whenever I use the userControl containing my Test property, I cannot bind anything to Test, only give it a static True or False

Comment: Why does "cannot bind" mean? What happens? And how do you bind?

Comment: I do `Test="{Binding *propertyName*}"` and get "Impossible to define 'Binding' on the 'Test' Property..."

Comment: There was `nameof(PropertyPath)` in the registration of the Test dependency property, which should of course be `nameof(Test)`. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Angevil: Are you really binding to the `Test` property of `DamageTemplateListEditableUserControl` then? Have you tried to build? Please provide a full reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: Clemens found a typo which corrected my build error ^^"